# Angularjs: Callback to parent controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please consider the following code: it has a directive `myItem` with isolate scope. Each item will display a button that will call `delete()` on the directive controller. I'd like this to trigger a `refresh` in the outer controller (`AppController`). But of course the `refresh()` function can not be found, because of the isolated scope.

```
   <html>
    <body ng-app="question">
        <div ng-cloak ng-controller="AppController">
            <my-item ng-repeat="item in list" data="list">
            </my-item>
            <input type="text" maxlength="50" ng-model="new_item" />
            <button ng-click="add(new_item)">+</button>
        </div>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
         (function () {
             var app;

             app = angular.module('question', []);


             app.controller('AppController', [
                 '$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
                     $scope.list = [];

                     function refresh(){
                         $http.get('/api/items').then(
                             function(response){
                                 $scope.list = response.data;
                             }
                         );
                     }

                     $scope.add = function(item){
                         $http.post('/api/items', { item: item }).then(refresh);
                     };

                     refresh();
                 }
             ]);

             app.directive('myItem', function() {
                 return {
                     scope: {
                         item: '=data',
                     },
                     // directive template with delete button
                     template: '{{ item }} <button ng-click="delete(item)">-</button>',
                     restrict: 'E',
                     // directive controller with delete function
                     controller: [ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
                         $scope.delete = function (card) {

// This is where it goes wrong! refresh does not exist
                             $http.delete('/api/items' + card.id).then(refresh);
                         }
                     }]
                 };
             });
         })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

One thing I could do is add ng-change to the myItem directive, but that would involve requiring ngModelController which seems overkill.

Other things I can think of:

1. Add something like `onchange: '@'` to the `scope` attribute of the directive, then set `onchange = refresh` in the html. Call the onchange expression instead of refresh inside the `delete` function. But this feels like I'm re-implementing  `ng-change`?
2. Add `require: '^AppController'` to the directive. Then I guess I could call `refresh` on the parent controller directly. That seems like it violates loose coupling.
3. Don't use isolate scope at all. That would mean we inherit from the parent scope and `refresh` is available. But then my directive implicitly assumes that the scope will hold an `item`. Which also violates loose coupling, but in an implicit way.

So my question is: which is the correct way to let the parent controller know it should refresh its contents?

Comment: what about utilizing the `$rootScope`?

Comment: @iam-decoder: I'm not aware of `$rootScope` and can't find a lot of helpful documentation quickly. How would it help me?

Comment: this logic seems to be implemented backwards anyway.  You want to issue a server call to `delete`, then immediately tell the parent controller that it should make a `get` call  to the server to figure out that the item really was deleted?  There are plenty of ways to handle deleting an item without it involving two separate server calls....

Comment: in fact, the directive really shouldn't be responsible for deleting the item at all in this instance.

Comment: So @Claies, you are saying the `ng-click` for the delete button should call a function on the parent controller (`ng-click="$parent.delete(item)"`)? And that `parent.delete()` should do `$http.delete(...).then( /* remove item from list client-side */)`. Right?

Comment: that would be one of the more common ways that the logic is implemented, yes.

Comment: I see your point, @Claies. Of course now I'm curious about the other common ways you might know about. And do you really think that doing that kind of bookkeeping clientside (adding logic, state and complexity) is worth it, just to save on a single HTTP GET?

Comment: a "single GET" could be a couple milliseconds or a couple minutes, depending on how much data is being trafficked. And on a heavily used site, it could add up to hundreds or thousands of excess network calls.  Also, if that data is being used for other logic, requesting a new copy of it could create unexpected states in other areas of the application, and make debugging quite a bit more difficult.

Comment: alternatives include using a service to maintain the state of the data, or using `$broadcast` to allow other areas of the application to respond to changes.  In general, it's best to limit components which communicate with the server whenever possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, the first way would be the best way. The directive receives a function callback from outside which is executed by the directive when necessary. Like this the two directives are loosely coupled. It's similar to ng-change which is an attribute that is used by ng-model directive.

Example: Directive

```
app.directive('myItem', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            item: '=data',
            myItemDeleteCallback: '&myItemDeleteCallback'
        },
        template: '{{ item }} <button ng-click="delete(item)">-</button>',
        controller: [ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.delete = function (card) {
                // This is where it goes wrong! refresh does not exist
                $http.delete('/api/items' + card.id).then(function () {
                    $scope.myItemDeleteCallback();
                });
            }
        }]
    };
});
```

Usage: Controller

```
app.controller('AppController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.list = [];

    $scope.refresh = function (){
        $http.get('/api/items').then(
            function(response){
                $scope.list = response.data;
            }
        );
    };

    $scope.add = function(item){
        $http.post('/api/items', { item: item })
            .then($scope.refresh);
    };

    refresh();
}]);
```

Usage: Template

```
<div ng-cloak ng-controller="AppController">
    <my-item my-item-delete-callback="refresh()" ng-repeat="item in list" data="list">
    </my-item>
    <input type="text" maxlength="50" ng-model="new_item" />
    <button ng-click="add(new_item)">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Just wondering, shouldn't it be `$scope.myItemDeleteCallback()` (dollar sign added in front)?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo and thanks for noticing it. It's already fixed.

Comment: Accepting this as the correct answer. Although @Claies makes a valid point in the discussion above, in my case his/her reasoning is a classic example of the pitfall called Premature Optimization :) In other words: keeping my code simple & clean while doing an extra GET is fine with me.